# Inject ENV variable to Cypress from Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, cypress

Using `Cypress` and `Azure Pipelines`, I'd like to inject an environment variable from the pipeline to be used in my tests following the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_)

In Azure, I have a library `Env-Dev` a variable `CYPRESS_TESTENV` set to "This is a test"

##### YAML Pipeline

```
jobs:
  - job: Cypress
    variables:
      - group: Env-Dev
    steps:
        - script: yarn start:server & cypress run
          env:
            CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: $(CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY)
            CYPRESS_TESTENV: $(CYPRESS_TESTENV) // Tried with and without this line
```

##### cypress.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    env: {
      TESTENV: '',
    },
  },
});
```

##### mytest.ts

```
cy.log(`ENV from pipeline ${Cypress.env('CYPRESS_TESTENV')}`);
```

### Expected result

`ENV from pipeline This is a test`

### Actual result

`ENV from pipeline undefined`

### Question

What am I missing? I originally assumed that using the variables group `Env-Dev` would be enough. Then I tried to re-inject in with `env` at the `script` level.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have this problem now

Comment: @offset I don't have the same issue anymore but I'm not sure what solved it. Right now I have a new library in Azure Devops called Cypress, and I'm using it in my YAML file. The variable name is CUSTOM_ENV, I still initialize it to empty string in cypress.config.ts